# Trying to Emulate KitKat in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, android-4.4-kitkat

I am trying to debug an app (with min. API 10) that runs fine on a real device running Nougat (API 24) but the app crashes during specific tasks on a real device running KitKat (API 19).

I use Android Studio.
I want to emulate a device running API 19 to understand what is making the app crash, using the bugger in Android Studio.

I created several new virtual devices in the Android Virtual Device Manager and selected the KitKat system image (API19) (Android 4.4.4) (google APIs), but when I launch the emulator for these devices, the emulator crashes after showing the Android logo. And I cannot reach the home screen.

I have no problem running API25 on emulated Nexus 5 or 6.

Where should I start looking to fix my issue ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the minimum API level?

Comment: is your application crashes or the emulator ?

Comment: The emulator crashes when started independently of the app.

Comment: the app minimum API level is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you are using the latest x86 Google APIs system images from the SDK Manager as well as the latest Android Emulator. As of writing this, it should be revision 29 for the API 19 system image (see screen shot):

[image: Android Studio SDK Manager]

Revision 29, should work:
[image: API 19 System Image v29]

To further troubleshoot, you can run the emulator from the command line to see any error output. To to this, run the following commands from your Android SDK location, as indicated in the Android Studio SDK Manager window.

1. *$ ./tools/bin/avdmanager list avd*     (this will list all AVDs on your machine, identify the API 19 AVD that you want to run and note the "Name:" field.
2. *$ ./emulator/emulator -avd Nexus_5_API_19*    (with Nexus_5_API_19 being the name of your AVD on your machine.)
3. Note any error messages. If you find an error with the emulator, you can file a bug here: https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html